# Powershell Word SaveAs command errors when run using a service account

Tags: powershell, ms-word

This has been driving me nuts for days.... I have a powershell script that converts all .doc files in a target directory to PDF's using Word SaveAs interop.
The script works fine when run within context of the logged in user, but errors with "***You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.***" when I try to execute the script using a service account (via task scheduler, run as another user)... service account has local admin rights.

The exception occurs at this line: **$Doc.SaveAs([ref]$Name.value,[ref]17)**

My code is as follows, Im not the best coder in the world so any advice would be gratefully received.
thanks.

```
try
{
$FileSource = 'D:\PROCESSOR\NewArrivals\*.doc'
$SuccessPath = 'D:\PROCESSOR\Success\'
$docextn='.doc'
$Files=Get-ChildItem -path $FileSource
$counter = 0
$filesProcessed = 0
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

#check files exist to be processed.
$WordFileCount = Get-ChildItem $FileSource -Filter *$docextn -File| Measure-Object | %{$_.Count} -ErrorAction Stop

If ($WordFileCount -gt 0) {

  Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $Name="$(($File.FullName).substring(0, $File.FullName.lastIndexOf("."))).pdf"

    $Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($File.FullName)
    $Doc.SaveAs([ref]$Name.value,[ref]17)
    $Doc.Close()

    if ($counter -gt 100) {
        $counter = 0
        $Word.Quit()
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word)
        $Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    }
    $counter = $counter + 1
    $filesProcessed = $filesProcessed + 1
}
}
$Word.Quit()
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word)
}

catch
{
}
finally
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain the service account has access to Word, then I think the exception you encounter is in the `[ref]` while doing the SaveAs().
AKAIK only Office versions below 2010 need `[ref]`, versions above do not.

Next I think your code can be tydied up somewhat, for instance by releasing the com objects ($Doc and $Word) inside the `finally` block, as that is always executed.
Also, there is no need to perform a `Get-ChildItem` twice.

Something like this:

```
$SuccessPath    = 'D:\PROCESSOR\Success'
$FileSource     = 'D:\PROCESSOR\NewArrivals'
$filesProcessed = 0

try {
    $Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $Word.Visible = $false
    # get a list of FileInfo objects that have the .doc extension and loop through
    Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource -Filter '*.doc' -File | ForEach-Object {
        # change the extension to pdf for the output file
        $pdf = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.FullName, '.pdf')
        $Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($_.FullName)

        # Check Version of Office Installed. Pre 2010 versions need the [ref]
        if ($word.Version -gt '14.0') {
            $Doc.SaveAs($pdf, 17)
        }
        else {
            $Doc.SaveAs([ref]$pdf,[ref]17)
        }
        $Doc.Close($false)
        $filesProcessed++
    }
}
finally {
    # cleanup code
    if ($Word) {
        $Word.Quit()
        $null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Doc)
        $null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word)
        [System.GC]::Collect()
        [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        $Word = $null
    }
}
```

Then, there is the question of `$SuccessPath`. You never use it. Is it your intention to save the PDF files in that path? If so, change the line

```
$pdf = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.FullName, '.pdf')
```

into

```
$pdf = Join-Path -Path $SuccessPath -ChildPath ([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Name, '.pdf'))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks @theo. Im using Word 2016 so have removed [ref] but still getting the same issue.  When trying to run your code I get an exception:  ForEach-Object : Argument: '1' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Use [ref].  At Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource -Filter '*.doc' -File | ForEach-Object {

Comment: @GBense Then are you sure the service account has access to the files in folder `$FileSource` ?

Comment: Yes, when my script is executed manually all works as expected. In addition i've checked permissions at file level are ok.

Comment: @GBense I cannot reproduce that error (or any error as a matter of fact) with the code above. Please make sure you copy/paste it as-is straight in the PowerShell editor (not via Word or Outlook, because then the quotes will become curly typographic thingies that do not belong in code)